# Form Sheet content disappearing

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to implement a form sheet. Here is what it looks like on Storyboard:
[image]

When i run the app only the background appear and everything else is hidden. 
I'm presenting the form sheet using Modally Presented - form sheet and i'm working with (wRegular hRegular) size. Why is that happening?

Comment: did you checked by changed the default inferred view to respected size

Comment: @ismail thanks for replying. Sorry I didn't get your comment.

Comment: i mean by removing the auto resize subviews options in interface builder document

Comment: @ismail I'm kind of relying on them in Storyboard. Could be there an alternative solution?